# Content Query Web Part - How do you OrderBy when you QueryOverride?

Tags: sharepoint, caml, sql-order-by, cqwp

How do you order items when you override the `QueryOverride` property of the Content Query Web Part?

I have been given responsibility for a Web Part which extends the Content Query Web Part. The `QueryOverride` property of this Web Part is programmatically changed. Currently, the Web Part does not function as designed, as it does not order the items according to the appropriate field.

If I add an `<OrderBy>` node to the `QueryOverride` property I get an error message along the lines of 'something wrong with the query this web part is...' and the Content Query Web Part doesn't seem to have an `OrderBy` property which I could use instead.

The "QueryOverride property" part of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx) msdn article seems to suggest I should be able to add an `<OrderBy>` node to the `QueryOverride` but a number of web sites I've been reading suggest that this is not true.

So, how do you order items when you override the `QueryOverride` property of the Content Query Web Part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your QueryOverride statement contain any Whitespace/linebreaks by any chance? I think I recall a while back having a situation where the QueryOverride needed to be all contained on one line, with no spaces between xml tags.

Weird I know, but try it out.

Also, for reference see the first community comment on the MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx

Comment: I'll try removing the line breaks... but it works _with_ line breaks if I exclude the `<OrderBy>`... is that consistent with what you remember?

Comment: It does ring a bell actually!

Comment: There are no words to describe the infinite extents of your awesomeness.

Comment: * thinks about it a little more * and Good Lord, SharePoint is pile of rubbish!

Comment: I'm going to have to go ahead and agree with you Richard.  The XML fetish with this product is completely out of hand.

Comment: The xml thing wouldn't be so bad if it behaved like xml. Well-formed xml is well formed xml IMHO. Another thing that gets me are "case-sensitive guids" that I come across from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

THanks for this. Just to clarify, there should be no white spaces before or after the tags as well.

This did not work:

```
<![CDATA[
   <OrderBy><FieldRef Name="EndDate" Ascending="False"/></OrderBy>
   <Where>
```

But this did:

```
<![CDATA[<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="EndDate" Ascending="False"/></OrderBy><Where>
```

Wierd but thanks again for posting this answer, it saved me a lot of time.